# STS does not work after changing jdk from 1.8 to 10

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I used jdk 1.8 in the STS latest version and changed it to jdk 10.
However, STS does not run.
When i run exe, i will see only the first logo and nothing more.
What is the problem?
I can not see the log because it is not running.

Comment: which version of STS  are you using? Did you check STS site ?

Comment: Can you find and post the STS's error log? Go to Window -> Show View -> Other -> General -> Error Log

Comment: The latest versions of STS (3.9.6) run on JDK 8-11. If you have trouble running that version, please add more details.